# Called form not starting at beginning of form code

Tags: c#, winforms

[using VS Community 2019 v16.10.4 on Win 10 Pro 202H]

I'm working on a C# Winforms desktop app which monitors some local drive properties and displays a status message. If a drive selected for monitoring is missing, an error message is displayed providing the user an option to plugin missing drives than rerun analysis.

When I plug-in the "missing" drive and rerun the scan/analysis, the change is not being picked up even though Windows Explorer/file manager is detecting the change.

If I terminate and than restart the debug session the change is picked up, and if I use a listbox (temporarily starting the window normal) to manually check re-instantiation, the changes are picked up.

The form getting data is the app entry; it performs data acquisition using a `BackgroundWorker`. It starts minimized and not shown in taskbar. I’ve set at breakpoint in error message form on the line creating the new instance of the initial form. When I step through (F11) it doesn’t start at the beginning of the initial form’s code but partway down where the percentComplete field is declared and assigned:

```
ReadinessStartup refresh = new ReadinessStartup(); //breakpoint here
refresh.Show();
```

```
public partial class ReadinessStartup : Form
{
    public static DriveInfo[] _allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
    private static readonly List<MonitorDrvs> _monitoredDrives =
             ConnectionConfig.Connects.GetMonitoring();

    private static System.Timers.Timer _myTimer;

    private readonly static int _mDrvsNum = _monitoredDrives.Count;
    private volatile bool _progFlag;
    private double _elapsedTime;
    private double _estTotal;
    private double _percentComplete = 0; // ENTERS FORM HERE ON F11
    private int _allDrvsNum;
    private int _progBarPC;

    public static bool _Refresh;

    public ReadinessStartup()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeBackgroundWorker();
        bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

So it appears it’s not picking up the changes because the required declaration is not being processed. Why isn’t the form code starting at the beginning?

Any help will be appreciated.

==== Elucidation Edit ====

to @Jimi comment: The solution has three projects; a Setup project,  a Monitoring project and a class Library.  Setup is executed from the Start Menu and Monitoring from Task Scheduler. _montoredDrives is defined in Setup and "consumed" in Monitoring. _allDrives and _montoredDrives are used in methods called in the BackgroundWorker DoWork to determine if drives identified for monitoring are currently missing or changed (on different disks/partitions).  DriveInfo[] is used rather than a list because various drive usage properties (specifically size, free & used space) are needed for analyses.

Comment: Remove `static` from `public static DriveInfo[]`. Not clear what this Field or `_monitoredDrives` are used for (used/set from the `DoWork` event of your BackgroundWorker?). It shouldn't be public either. -- If you need fresh info, you have to call `DriveInfo.GetDrives()` when needed. The array content doesn't update by itself (it should probably be a `List<DriveInfo>`).

Comment: @Jimi I had already added a "JIT" call to DriveInfo.GetDrives( ) in the method where it is first needed but I was considering it a "work-around"; guess it isn't.  The GetDrives statement is derived from the Microsoft example and, yes, it should be private but why should the "static" be removed (I'm only a beginner)?

Comment: Otherwise it's initialized *statically*: only when the first instance of the class it belongs to is initialized. No more. So you have will only ever have a *static* representation of the `DriveInfo` results (as an initialized array). -- Three's no reason to have that `_allDrives` collection *static* there, when it's a *dynamic* value. You can query `DriveInfo.GetDrives()` whenever needed.

Answer (score -2):

The fields are declared at compile time. Thats why the debugger isnt picking it up. The reason it starts at percentComplete is due to the assignment, which is done at runtime

Edit: ignore this answer (stays here for historical purposes). Seems my understanding of static is wrong

Comment: So compile only once and run as needed but isn't "public static DriveInfo[] _allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives( );" also an assignment?

Comment: Yes, but that is done at program start, so i assume the debugger doesn't pick it up, as it doesn't run when the class is instantiated, but when the program starts

Comment: @DownloadPizza - It's not run at program start. It's run as soon as any `static` member is accessed on `ReadinessStartup` or when an instance of `ReadinessStartup` is created.